# Post Study Work Visa United Kingdom 2 Years

Tags: united-kingdom

Am I eligible for a PSW (2 year Post-Study Work Visa UK):

Course: Masters of science
Method of study: Full Time
Start date: 6 January 2020
Estimated end date: 6 May 2021

Comment: According to recent announcements, you’d need to have valid UK immigration status as a student and have successfully completed a course of study in any subject at undergraduate level or above at an approved UK Higher Education Provider.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Before the Tier 1 (Post-study work) was withdrawn, a graduate of an accredited Masters programme would have been eligible for two years leave to remain on the route. [The government has indicated](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-announces-2-year-post-study-work-visa-for-international-students) that they intend to revive the route under roughly the same rules for the 2020 intake of students. However, they have not yet made the required changes to the Immigration Rules, and with the current extremely unstable political situation, it's entirely possible that these changes will not take place, and that the Tier 1 (Post-study work) route will not reopen.

It is most likely that you will be eligible, but you should be prepared for the possibility that the route does not reopen.